# Nunit tests are not shown in Test Explorer of VS2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nunit

I have visual studio 2013 express edition and I have referenced NUnit 2.6.2 version DLL, but I don't know why the Test Explorer is not showing the test cases.

I did searched for questions with similar problem and tried doing what suggested like the Nunit Framework from NuGet package and making sure the Nunit reference and adapter version are correct, etc. but none of them resolved the issue.

Right now I have cleaned up everything from my Visual Studio and have only Nunit 2.6.2 DLL added in reference.
Following is the out put from Package manager console.

```
PM> Get-Package
No packages installed.
```

Can someone please help me to know how to get the Nunit tests in my Test Explorer ?

Comment: Yes, I added the Nunit 3 adapter but that also did not helped hence I removed (uninstalled) it

Answer (score 1):

You need the [NUnit Test Adapter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NUnitDevelopers.NUnitTestAdapter) and not the NUnit 3 Test Adapter since you are using version 2.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry... The NUnit Test Adapter and the NUnit 3 Test Adapter are both Visual Studio extensions. The Express editions of Visual Studio don't support extensions. Period.

You need to switch to either VS2015 or VS2017 Community Edition, which do support extensions. Then you can install either of the two adapters - depending on what version of the NUnit framework you are using.